# adding django admin many-to-many widget

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In the [django admin documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models), it says the following:

> By default, admin widgets for many-to-many relations will be displayed on whichever model contains the actual reference to the ManyToManyField.

Is there a way to get a similar widget to appear on the admin page for the other model, the one where the relationship isn't defined?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different ways to get the effect that you're after.

Here's one way, which will get you a similar (but not identical) effect, and probably requires the least coding. (Examples will use classes `A` and `B`, assuming that the former has the many to many relationship explicitly defined)

The quickest way: you can use an `InlineModelAdmin` object:

```
class AInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = A

class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (AInline,)
admin.site.register(B, BAdmin)
```

If you want the *exact* effect of getting a `<select multiple>`, the way you can do it is to use a custom `Form` class, and assign it to `BAdmin.form`.